# How to select values from many rows that has the same id to just one row and separate them with -?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, string-aggregation

i'd like to display the values of the table with the same id in just one row and separate them  with `-` or,

```
 row id | base_id | auth_id
--------+---------+---------
      4 |       1 |       1
      5 |       1 |       3
      6 |       2 |       2
      7 |       2 |       6
      8 |       2 |       5
```

result i expect

```
 row id | base_id | auth_id
--------+---------+---------
      1 |       1 | 1-3
      2 |       2 | 2-6-5
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  They are different databases.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i'm using postgres

Comment: Are you **really** still using Postgres 9.1? In that case, you should plan the upgrade to the current (supported) version now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) concatenation and `row_number()` window analytic function :

```
select row_number() over (order by base_id) as row_id, 
       base_id, string_agg(auth_id::varchar,'-' order by auth_id) as auth_id
  from tab
 group by base_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=83c383b58a414a8339c5b3933557230f)</kbd>

Comment: the compiler says "the function string_agg() doesn't exist"

Comment: @RezaPratama yes, casting to varchar needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option using `string_agg`:

```
select
    row_number() over (order by base_id) row_id,
    base_id,
    string_agg(auth_id, '-' order by auth_id)
from your_table
group by
    base_id
order by
    base_id;
```